# munin is not showing all Ethernet ports

Tags: linux, vmware, munin

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 running on a VmWare ESXi. I'm trying to run munin on the Linux system to show the status of the system. But in the network tab of munin only eth0 is shown even though `ifconfig` shows eth0, eth1 and lo.

Are there any settings I have to change to show all ports?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the plugin `if_err`. From the munin plugin file:

```
This is a wildcard plugin. To monitor an interface, link
if_err_<interface> to this file. E.g.

  ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/if_err_ \
        /etc/munin/plugins/if_err_eth0

...will monitor eth0.
```

Comment: eth0 is already linked. And What i need is I need to see traffic details of eth1.

Comment: Also the traffic through eth1 is UDP, can that affect this??

Comment: You need one link per interface.